# Rails Calendar with spanning Events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, calendar

I am in need to build a calendar that allows for events that span multiple days.

I have used Ryan Bates Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised as a setup but it will only display the event start date.

Is there an easy way to build off this to allow an event to span multiple days?

People have suggested Full Calendar as an alternative, but my data relies heavily on the conditions built within the controller which advises it what events to show on a particular page.